# Enable TLS 1.1/1.2 for Android 4.X in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, ssl

I'm in the process of making a React Native app that has a `minSdkVersion` of 16 (Android 4.1). It makes requests to HTTPS pages where the server has disabled TLS 1.0. From my understanding Android 4.X has TLS 1.1/1.2 capabilities, but they need to be invoked specifically. I found several people claiming to fix this, but those seem like pure Java solutions. For example:

- [Support for TLS 1.1 and 1.2 on Android 4.x](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7192)
- [support enabling TLSv1.2 on Android 4.1-4.4.](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2372)

Even with all that talk, what I can't wrap my head around and am wonder is this:

- Is it possible to solve this in any way **without** forking React Native?

I see [this commit](https://github.com/bringnow/react-native/commit/fc7d451fdfcd0659b5cd279fb13161d20d12721d) which seems like a feasible solution, but it does invade into the React Native source code, and I'd prefer to not have possible conflicts there in the future. I also see that you can [create a custom `SSLSocketFactory`](https://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/), but then how do I make all the requests through React Native use that factory? I also hear that you might have to [update the device SSL version](https://medium.com/tech-quizlet/working-with-tls-1-2-on-android-4-4-and-lower-f4f5205629a) in some cases, but that doesn't really help if I can't invoke TLS 1.1/1.2 for my requests.

Answer (score 6):

After numerous attempts to solve it, there is only one way that worked for me. Essentially you need to add a Java security package from Google to enable TLSv1/ TLSv1.1/ TLSv1.2 on old Android versions (< 5.0). This will also add support for TLSv1.3 as well as increase the apk size, but I guess we'll have to live with it.

Add the package in `app/build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.1.0'
```

Update `MainApplication.java` to use the new security provider:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();

Security.insertProviderAt(new org.conscrypt.OpenSSLProvider(), 1);

//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this is the SSL issue. If I true you can try the following steps:

1. Create a Java class `SSLCertificateHandler` to enable SSL with the function below:

   ```
   public static void trustSSL() {
   try {
       TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
           public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
               X509Certificate[] myTrustedAnchors = new X509Certificate[0];
               return myTrustedAnchors;
           }

           @Override
           public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
           }

           @Override
           public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
           }
       } };

       SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
       sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
       HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
       HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
           @Override
           public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
               return true;
           }
       });
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }}
   ```
2. Call it from MainApplication class:

   ```
   public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   SSLCertificateHandler.trustSSL();}
   ```

Comment: react-native does not use HttpsURLConnection in the background, it uses the okhttp3 library, I don't think your answer is valid.

Comment: Why okhttp3 doesn't use `HttpsURLConnection `? I used `okhttp3` for my Android  project and above code to by pass SSL/TLS issue.